# Auto instantiate/load multiple consumers and producers

Tags: python, apache-kafka

We are working on a design where we will have 'N' number of consumers and producers. Operationally, is there a way in kafka or zookeeper to automatically load these in a cluster?

Comment: This isn't a server issue, so I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for as far as "loading into". Can you please clarify your current issue with creating multiples of these? In particular, do you have only one process with multiple clients (using the same topic) or are you starting more than one application process at a time? (because that's the proper way to scale Kafka clients)

Comment: I'm asking how does one automatically load a set of consumer/producers clients. And, yes, are intent is to start more than one application process.

Comment: And I'm trying to get you to clarify what you mean by "automatic". What does your process look like so far to run the code? What issues are you having with scaling that? Nothing is automatic. You'll need to actually create those application processes yourself, whether that's via some autoscaling group or explicit replicas / supervised processes

Comment: +1 That was what I was looking for. So what I do now (in dev) is start cluster, manually spawn consumer, manually spawn producers, etc. I can certainly create a script to do this but thought to ask before committing to that.

Comment: Kubernetes/Docker Swarm/Nomad `replicas` config? Python `supervisor`? A shell script with a loop? All of these are valid ways to start multiple processes

Comment: Yes, know all those. My question was about anything in Kafka itself providing that capability.

Comment: Kafka brokers don't run client applications or provides any guidance on how they are managed, no. Kafka Connect/Streams, however do offer configuration properties that do automatically balance tasks/threads within deployed applications (still requires external OS process supervision)